# Button onclick event with electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

So, I have an electron app, and I want to execute shell command on button click. I can't really find any helpful tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@cloudzik try this method:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: I meant to add event when button is clicked. Button clicked -> Shell script is executed. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Shell command can only be executed on backend. Means you have to emit an event from your button to the background. Then execute command with child process like @enist suggested.